# How to make non constant bevel

Tags: modeling, mesh, bevel

[image]

Hello everyone:

here's my problem, I need a bevel that will blend the right block and left block together but the right block is hexagonal shaped, and the left one square based. So to summarize the bevel should reach the edges of the left block in a smooth way. I come from SolidWorks and have no idea how to do that in Blender. The supposed look:[image]

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I would suggest to bridge between the hexagonal and the rounded square shaped part. You should though make sure to have equally amounts of vertices on each loop of the shapes, so the bridging works best.